# Why did "けっぱる", "You got this!" or "I got this!" got translated to "拼冲天"？

Tags: meaning, word-choice, terminology, google-translate

In Pokemon Scarlet/Violet, the character Kieran often said "拼冲天" during the climax of the battle or when he tries to encourage himself.

1. The first instance of this is when Kieran battles the player at the shrine.

Chinese version: "还有挽回的机会！**拼冲天**. . . . . .**拼冲天**！"

English version:
"I can come back from this! **I got this**. . .**I got this**!"

Japanese version:
まだ 挽回できる！
けつばれ. . . . . . **けっぱる**！

2. The second instances is when Kieran tries to catch Ogerpon in the player's place.

Chinese version: 就算运气不眷顾我，我也会**拼冲天**的. . . . . .！

English version: Guess luck isn't on my side... But it doesn't matter-**I got this**!

Japanese version:
運に 見放されたって
おれ **けっぱるから**. . . . . .！

3. The third instances is when the player is about to catch Terapagos.

Chinese version:"我相信交给（player's name）你一定没问题。. . . . . .**拼冲天**！"

English version: "I know I can count on you, (player's name). **You got this**!"

Japanese version: (player's name)になら まかせられる
. . . . .**けっぱる**！

I am wondering why the translation team uses **拼冲天** instead of something like:"**你能行的**！" or "**你可以的**"。As I find **拼冲天** to be an interesting choice to make. My understanding is that it means "拼命往天冲" or “Reach for the sky”. Also, does any one know what the original Japanese text "**けつばれ**" and "**けっぱるから**" means? I got translation such as "Too bad", “purging the blood”，"太糟糕了", or even “加油”. These all seems inconsistent, does anyone know what the Japanese terms means?

Comment: I want to grab the translator and shake him awake,  "What the hell is that?!"

Comment: Actually, I wanted to grab whoever yelled "拼冲天", and tell him: "Please stop using that phrase, I feel sick hearing it"

Comment: Don't worry, the DLC is short enough

Comment: Usually for Pokemon we need to look at the original Japanese version to find out what his catch-phrase really is. The English version is also a translation.

Comment: I will update this post with the Japanese text when I get the chance.

Comment: I have added the Japanese text, the translation all seems inconsistent.

Comment: Google translate - "けっぱるから(I'll kick it; 我会踢它)", "けつばれ(Asshole; 混蛋)".

Comment: My guess:  "拼冲天" - 拼了, 一沖上天! (比喻志气超迈或情绪高涨而猛烈.)

Comment: Very good, you could press the "Post Your Anwser" button if you want. Hahaha

Comment: Yeah, I got 混蛋 from google translate too, just too awkward to mention it in my post. ╮( •́ω•̀ )╭

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and searching online, the original けっぱるから could be a phrase for encouragement. It translates to **I will kick it/我会踢它**

けっぱる could possibly be a abbreviation/缩写. Directly translating it will get a bad word. However, using Baidu translate will get a simple **加油** for Chinese. For English, it's **get** **off** or "**to do your best**".

The Chinese translation, 拼冲天, I originally guess was that it means "**拼命冲向天**"/“Reach for the sky”. However, the comments has stated that it could be "**拼了, 一沖上天!**" As Baidu also stated the same for the definition of "冲天", being

"1.直向天空。2.比喻志气超迈或情绪高涨而猛烈。 3.谓向最高统治者告发。"

(1. Point straight to the sky.  2. A metaphor for high ambition or high and intense emotions.  3. To report to the supreme ruler.)

This makes sense as Kieran was in a intense emotional state during the battles. Thirsting for more power before his 黑化. Of course, he uses the phrase to encourage the player later on.

Comment: けっぱる means がんばる (加油) in northern dialects of Japanese. けっぱれ is its imperative form. けつはれ and けつばれ must be typos.

Comment: I just recheck. You are correct! I will change it to けっぱる. Also, thansk for the clarification, I can't seems to find dialects difference online.